# What are the current options for getting from SJD airport to Cabo San Lucas and vice versa?

Tags: airport-transfer, mexico, sjd, los-cabos

As of 2019, what are the options for getting to/from Cabo San Lucas from [Los Cabos airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Cabos_International_Airport)? The options I'm aware of are:

- Official taxi
- Uber is available, but they can't pick up passengers from the airport
- There are shared shuttles leaving the airport
- There's apparently a cheap public bus, but I couldn't locate exact details

Bonus points for sharing the easiest way to catch an Uber on the way from the airport. Perhaps one can take one stop on the public bus and then get an Uber from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current options are (all prices quoted in USD):

1. Take a taxi, either pre-booked or directly from a taxi stand at the airport. For example [Cabo Transfers](https://www.cabotransfers.com/rates) charges $85 for a one-way trip to/from the airport. Travel time is 40 minutes.
2. Uber cannot pickup passengers at the airport due to pressure from the taxi industry, but you can use them to get from Cabo San Lucas to the airport. Uber's [price estimate](https://www.uber.com/mx/en/price-estimate/) shows an average price of $40. Travel time is 40 minutes, just like with official taxis.

   You can also take the public bus for $5 first to reach San Jose Del Cabo and then take an Uber from there for $20. The total travel time would be around 1 hour.
3. Take a shared shuttle. You don't need to book these when going from the airport, but need a reservation 24 hours in advance when going from Cabo San Lucas. [Cabo Transfers](https://www.cabotransfers.com/rates) charges $21 for a one way trip and other companies should have similar pricing. Travel time is between 60 and 90 minutes, depending on how many stops your shuttle will make and how long you'll wait for it to fill up.
4. Take the public bus, run by a company called [Ruta del Desierto](https://www.facebook.com/Ruta-del-Desierto-227487254101762/). A one-way ticket from the airport costs 85 MXN / 5 USD, as shown in the infographic below. The buses run both from Terminal 1 and Terminal 2 every 15 minutes. The bus stop in Terminal 1 (the domestic terminal) is right in front of the building. In Terminal 2 (the international terminal) it's on the second floor where the Departures are, right above the taxi stands.

   In Cabo San Lucas they stop in [Paradero](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bus+Stop+(Ruta+Del+Desierto+%2F+Desert+Drive)/@22.8885321,-109.9160923,15.48z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xe0b05937dcd6de77!8m2!3d22.8894037!4d-109.9098437), next to the Marina and at the [Aguila bus station](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Transportes+%C3%81guila/@22.8915857,-109.9320787,15.33z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x86af4a60709976a7:0x942e0370dc13572b!8m2!3d22.8985597!4d-109.9264419). Total travel time is 80 minutes, as of December 2019.

[image]

Overall I recommend either taking the bus all the way or taking one stop and then taking an Uber. Neither the taxi nor the shuttle make financial sense if at least two people are traveling together.