# What are the taxi options at Puerto Vallarta airport?

Tags: mexico, taxis, puerto-vallarta

I'm arriving at Puerto Vallarta ([PVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licenciado_Gustavo_D%C3%ADaz_Ordaz_International_Airport)) airport soon and would like to take a taxi. What are my options?

Comment: Vaguely related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/150566/what-are-the-current-options-for-getting-from-sjd-airport-to-cabo-san-lucas-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Official airport taxi

After you exit customs and go past the numerous taxi touts, there's an office selling "official" taxi trips. You can pay in cash (MXN/USD) or by credit card. After pre-paying, you get a slip that you give to the taxi driver outside after waiting in line. The rates are [posted on this website](https://aeromovilpvr.com/puerto-vallarta-airport-taxi-rates/) and are about **2x more expensive than Uber**.

When I arrived in December 2023 the official taxi line was quite chaotic and we've waited for 15 minutes outside in the sun. But there's probably less busy times when the wait times are lower.

#### Uber

Due to the presence of a "taxi mafia" at the airport, Uber drivers are not allowed to pick up passengers from the terminal. Instead, you must cross over the pedestrian bridge in the south-east corner of the airport to get to the [Uber pickup spot](https://maps.app.goo.gl/16wA28YGv7RzqefU9). The bridge is wheelchair-friendly and thus it's not too hard to cross over it with suitcases.

When going back to the airport, Uber is allowed to drop you off directly at the terminal. Overall I'd say this is a superior option to the "official" taxi unless you have *a lot* of luggage.

### InDrive and Didi

As per Reddit, the most popular local taxi apps are [InDrive](https://indrive.com/en/home/) and [Didi](https://web.didiglobal.com/mx/pasajero/) but I haven't tried them during my stay. If Uber doesn't work for you for some reason, I'd give them a try.